# Finding a path from a thick line

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, graph-algorithm

I am trying to find or think of an algorithm that finds a path from a thick line. I think the images make easier to understand what I am trying to do.

[image: Thick line without path]

[image: Thick line with past]

Given is a 2D array as the picture with values 0 and 1 and I am trying to find the nodes of the lines. Has anybody an idea?

Comment: Any side conditions like poly-line with as few segments as possible?

Comment: Number of lines can be variable if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could follow the contour and nibble away pixel by pixel (checking that the connectivity stays intact).

If you cannot remove any more pixels, you have a 1 pixel line as wanted.

But the line will most likely have very few long linear segments (unlike in your example)

Comment: There would still be the question how to decide which pixel to "nibble" so that the result makes sense

Comment: Go along the border and remove on at a time while following the contour. After several rounds you'll be finished. "so that the result makes sense" was not defined in your question, so I cannot answer that part.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the most famous python library for image treatment : Pillow.
https://python-pillow.org/

Some questions to orientate you :

- Is it really black and white source image ? If No, the first step will be to make each pixel of this picture either black or white (pillow proposes this feature)
- Is the width of the white pattern constant (i.e. always 15 pixels) ? If No, your program will first need to scan first the whole picture and then to guess the pattern. If Yes, you can guess the pattern while scanning the picture.

But what means "scanning the picture" ?
That's the key question.
You could check all lines of pixels (from the first line till the last line, and for each line, from left to right), each time you encounter a white pixel you record its coordinates and you record how many white pixels are aside this first white pixel.
Doing that, you will get a table where all white pixels are located.
Then, it's more about mathemtics than about programming.

Comment: Finding the white pixels is not the problem. My problem is about finding the poly-line when you already have the pixels.